AWS issues module import issues
I am having "fun" with the AWS PowerShell module.
I had to install a new AWS module over the original one because it was not possible to uninstall the original.
PS C:\Users\Administrator.MS-AA> UnInstall-Module -Name AWSPowerShell -Force
WARNING: The version '4.1.582' of module 'AWSPowerShell' is currently in use. Retry the operation after closing the applications.
PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : Module 'AWSPowerShell' is in currently in use or you don't have the required permissions.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2194 char:21
+ ...        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleIsInUse,Uninstall-Package,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage

After installing the new AWS module, it gives the following range of errors similar to:
    "Error in TypeData "Amazon.EC2.Model.Region": The member Region is already present". 

As a result, the import command doesn't work, and the desired SQS command fails with the following:
     "Error receiving messages: The 'Receive-SQSMessage' command was found in the module 'AWSPowerShell', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module AWSPowerShell'.
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException"

Also, the package list is awkward:
PS C:\Users\Administrator.MS-AA> Get-Package | findstr AWS
AWS Tools for Windows          3.15.1620                                         msi
AWS PV Drivers                 8.4.1                                             msi
AWSPowerShell                  4.1.582          https://www.powershellgallery... PowerShellGet

Any ideas?
Best regards

Did you install it on a machine that already had a previous version installed? Looks like conflicting type data files from multiple installations

Please add these important details to your post :)

Check TaskManager -> (More Details) -> Details tab, do you have multiple open powershell sessions? (ie powershell.exe, powershell_ise.exe listed - could also be another user, a scheduled task or something using the module). If theres only 1 powershell running, close it, then from CMD run powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "UnInstall-Module -Name AWSPowerShell -Force" - it could be the powershell your using to uninstall the module is the culprit of 'AWSPowerShell' is currently in use error.

MisterSmith's suggestion worked! I have removed the offending module and can continue.
Thank you Mr.Smith! ;-)
